# Typo3 - backup SYMLINK FOLDERS / FILES

Tags: typo3

i want to backup the typo3 Filesystem with FTP/Shell.

The structure is as follows:

```
FOLDERS
fileadmin
t3lib
typo3_src
typo3
typo3conf
typo3temp
uploads
FILES
index.php
...
```

Now the 3 folders and 1 file are SYMLINKS and therefore will not be Backuped by my Script

```
t3lib    
typo3_src    
typo3
index.php
```

Known:
all the SYMLINKS go back to typo3_src/typo3_src-6.1.1

My Questions:

Are those SYMLINKS static so i only have to save them once?

How would you backup under this condition and how to restore?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do not need to patch the files on your own (which should usually not happen) they are static. So you can save a copy from get.typo3.org/6.1.1 there is no need to copy the sources/symlinks. I guess it would be enough to just save which version you has been used, because you can get the sources from get.typo3.org again (but i do not know, what happens with outdated versions).